# Linq statement to get matches from 2 separate collections

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following scenario:

```
List<int> idCollection = new List<int>();
idCollection.Add(1);
idCollection.Add(2);
```

I'm trying to create an `IQueryable` in C# that will match the ID property on an Entity Framework model property to any of the IDs in my `idCollection`. Something like this:

```
IQueryable<Foo> query = context.Where(p => p.ID == [any ID contained in idCollection]);
```

Calling `ToList()` at this point is not an option, as I'm creating a dynamic search and the result set could be quite large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
IQueryable<Foo> query = context.Where(p => idCollection.Contains(p.ID));
```

### Additional

For Not selecting idCollection Elements

```
IQueryable<Foo> query = context.Where(p => !idCollection.Contains(p.ID));
```

Comment: Exactly what was required! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Contains`

```
IQueryable<Foo> query = context.Where(p => idCollection.Contains(p.ID))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query must be something like this

```
IQueryable<Foo> query = context.Where(p => idCollection.Any(i=>i==p.ID ));
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
string[] collection1 = new string[] { "1", "7", "4" };
string[] collection2 = new string[] { "6", "1", "7" };

var resultSet = collection1.Intersect<string>(collection2);

foreach (string s in resultSet)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```